# How to access iPhone general accessibility settings with OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, application-settings

I want to access the general settings of iPhone. I know that it was not possible with os 3.0 and there on .

But hope fully if apple has provided any API with os 4.0 or above to access the general settings like if I want to know whether device is in vibrate mode or Ringing mode as well as

If I want to know whether my iPhone is having high brightness and If I want to set lower

To access such kind of settings does apple provide ani API.

If yes then please provide me the link.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the latest version of iOS. There is a private API which allows you to do it, but I heard that a flashlight app was rejected because of the use of a private API.

I don't know what type of app you are creating, but you could modify the colours of your content to make the appearance of it less bright? Just a suggestion!

Comment: Hey Chris Grant , Thanks for immediate reply. Can you give me the name of Private API that was used by flashlight app  ?

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740261/iphone-brightness-private-api-not-working-properly

Apparently he is using this API:
[(id)[UIApplication sharedApplication] setBacklightLevel:1.0f];  Bear in mind that you won't be able to submit to the app store if you do use this though.