# How to programatically detect backlight is on in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, backlight

I want iOS code that can show if the screen is lit or not, so that my app can monitor battery power drain due to the (power hungry) backlight activity.  This code must use the public API only, as I intend to submit the app to the App Store eventually.

Initially I thought this may be simply a matter of checking the [brightness](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness) property of the UIScreen, like so:

```
-(BOOL)isBackLightOn {
    float brightness = [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness;
    return brightness > 0;
}
```

but this is **incorrect** because `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness` represents the value of the slider chosen by the user in the Settings->Brightness screen, **not** the current light output of the screen.

Apple clearly have a way to determine this value, since it is included in the energy diagnostics that can be viewed in Instruments (e.g. see [Logging Energy Usage in an iOS Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-energy-measurement-help/Logging_Energy_Usage_in_an_iOS_Device/10_Logging_Energy_Usage_in_an_iOS_Device.html)), but maybe this measurement has not been exposed through the public API?

Answer (score 0):

A question that may help yo with this is:

[Changing Backlight Level, iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777470/changing-backlight-level-iphone?rq=1)

It seems that if you include this:

```
#include "GraphicsServices.h"
```

And then using something like this:

```
NSNumber *bl = (NSNumber*) CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("SBBacklightLevel" ), CFSTR("com.apple.springboard"));
float previousBacklightLevel = [bl floatValue];
```

Should give you the backlight level.  Remember, the screen is always going to have some form of backlight.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been explicit about needing to do this via public APIs (since I hope to submit the app to the App Store at some point).  I'll edit the question to state this.

Comment: what is this #include "GraphicsServices.h" ?

Comment: @HiRen GraphicsServices is part of the iOS SDK.

Comment: @Flipper whenever I tried to implement it's give me error like file not found have you try out ?

Answer (score 0):

First of I have tried @Flipper's answer but it's not helped me a lot then I have R&D on this and i have found a solution with the below code

```
    NSLog(@"%f", [[[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist"] objectForKey:@"SBBacklightLevel2"] floatValue]);
```

It's give me the float value, the current brightness level of the device